# Looping through a tuple in a class template, inserting vector elements

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is in the code:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct TupleOfVectorsOfVectors {
  std::tuple<std::vector<std::vector<Ts>>...> tuple;

  TupleOfVectorsOfVectors () {
    //Here we already have a tuple of empty vectors.
    //Question: How can I loop through those vectors
    //and push_back into each of them an empty vector?
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you using a tuple of vectors instead of a vector of vectors?

Comment: Tuples are to hold heterogeneous types, when you are only using one type (`std::vector<std::vector<T>>`). Why is this needed here?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Actually I have a tuple of vectors of maps, and want to push_back an empty map, but I thought I'd keep it simple in my question.

Comment: May be it worth using some intelligent data structure instead of vector of vectors (which can aggregate vectors, but also setups it in its constructor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand the parameter pack inside the initialization list. Using uniform initialization, I think this works:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct TupleOfVectorsOfVectors {
  std::tuple< std::vector<std::vector<Ts>> ... > tuple;

  TupleOfVectorsOfVectors ()
    : tuple { std::vector<std::vector<Ts>> { std::vector<Ts>() }... }
  { }
};

int main()
{
    TupleOfVectorsOfVectors<int, float> t;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t.tuple).size()
              << std::get<1>(t.tuple).size(); // prints 11, as expected
}
```

You can also do it at the member initializer (thanks to @JonathanWakely):

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct TupleOfVectorsOfVectors {
  std::tuple< std::vector<std::vector<Ts>> ... > tuple
     { { std::vector<Ts>() }... }; // mem-initializer

  TupleOfVectorsOfVectors ()
  { }
};
```

Comment: Nice, although the mem-initializer could be simpler: `tuple{ { std::vector<Ts>() }... }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I forgot you can do it there, too. Thanks, updated.

Comment: I actually meant the constructor initializer could be simpler, but yes, you can also do it with a non-static data member initializer

Comment: Is possible to somehow do this using only the `tuple` variable, without relying on `Ts`? Maybe using some `decltype` tricks?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah yes. I got a bunch of warnings about it being deduced as initializer list when I did that, so I just posted the version that compiled cleanly.

Comment: @7cows in the body of constructor, you mean? Yes, you could use indices trick and `std::get`, but you still need to expand a pack of indices somewhere. Another way would be to recursively call a template function to push_back on the first member of the tuple, but I believe that's inferior to intiialization.

Comment: Ok, that's cool. I may post a new question about that case later :)